# jQuery percentage calculation round up

Tags: jquery

I have a payment form, the client requested an additional 2.5% charge on the total, after some playing I have come up with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#amount').keyup(function(){
    $('#pay_amount').val($('#amount').val() * 1.025);
});   
});
```

You can see it working here:
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y3k2rkwb/)

My question/issue is can the total be rounded up/down to just two digits e.g. if you add the amount as "6" the total is: 6.1499999999999995 can this be 6.14 or rounded up to 6.15 
Same if you enter "100"

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following statement to this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#amount').keyup(function(){
    var amount=($('#amount').val()*1.025).toFixed(2)
    $('#pay_amount').val(amount);
});   
})
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, worked great, a lot less work than I assumed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#amount').keyup(function(){
    var thevalue = ($('#amount').val() * 1.025);
        $('#pay_amount').val(thevalue.toFixed);
    });   
});
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the formatted string, you can use `value.toFixed(2)`.

If you need the value to remain a number, then use `Math.round(value * 100)/100`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#amount').keyup(function(){
    var value = $('#amount').val() * 1.025;
    value = Math.round(value * 100) / 100;
    $('#pay_amount').val(value);
  });   
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
toFixed()
```

try that out see if it works for you here is a link to help you http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/01/jquery-round-off-decimal-values.html